# How to cache and reuse data shared between multiple users?

Tags: java, tomcat, caching

I am currently working on a webapp where case investigation details will be stored and displayed to the end user. The investigation details is a shared data where all the users who worked in that investigation(user permissions are provided) can view and edit the data. We have planned for a feature to show all the investigation over a year/month under one window. In such case we need to fetch a huge details over the network, as we can have multiple department working in multiple investigations(in their departments  as well as other departments too). So the data fetched in pretty huge(even though I fetch only the basic details of those investigations).

I make a request for every year/month. There is an option for navigating to and fro and when the user comes back to a year/month which he has already seen, i make the request and fetch the data once again(this is done because the investigation details are dynamic and shared b/w users. Also any user at any moment may modify it too). Caching was one of the option suggested but i am unsure when to cache and when to stale the cached data. Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You could store a 'last updated' timestamp with each investigative detail so that you reload only those that have actually changed since last access, to avoid sending each user a full copy of everything every single request. Use local browser storage to maintain some (most) state. Some (but not all) requests may trigger a full reload, perhaps on login/periodically/first access after certain time?

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BasilBourque is the title clear?

Comment: Both your title and question are much too vague and broad for us to provide any kind of answer. You have not described the kinds & amounts of data, the network topology (local network? internet? fast routers/switches?), the kinds of clients, where this cached data would live, if you are using a database and if so what kind, and other important details.

Comment: My first wild guess: You are falling for the old trap of *premature optimization*. Don't worry about a scalability problem until you have demonstrated its existence. Build a rough version of your system, load it up with realistic amounts of fake data, and experiment. Given that this is for "case investigation", I would be much more concerned about security than performance.

Comment: Yes you are right @BasilBourque, I am trying to optimise and increase performance as much as possible. Also, the caching is an idea to render the view quickly. If there is another technique which helps to transfer data or render view quickly over the network, I am open to explore. This is not used within our local network but open to all internet user(except this feature is not open to all). The data is in our database and in worst case the time taken was around 2 to 3 seconds at good internet connection. This was the prime reason why i was looking for some optimisation technique.